# Datepicker isn't working?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have downloaded the jqueryui and set it up .. in my project folder. then I integrate my HTML file with the links and scripts. after that, i called a tag with id datepicker. but nothing is happening. I don't knowwhat is happening? I am using Xampp. I don't see anything else wrong.

I thought the script is not working inside the head tag. So i replaced it and set it inside the body... After the result is same... there is no datepicker inside our input field.

```
<?php require_once 'header_link.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Report | Date wise report </title>

    <?php include("css.php");?>

    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link href="../vendors/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../vendors/datatables.net-scroller-bs/css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.min.css">







  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">
            <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
              <a href="dashboard.php" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Admin Panel</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <!-- menu profile quick info -->
            <div class="profile clearfix">
              <div class="profile_pic">
                <img src="<?php echo $my_tools->userImage();?>" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
              </div>
              <div class="profile_info">
                <span>Welcome,</span>
                <h2> <?php $my_tools->fullname();?></h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /menu profile quick info -->

            <br />

            <!-- sidebar menu -->
            <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
              <div class="menu_section">
                <h3>Main Menu </h3>
                <?php $my_tools->adminMenu();?>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /sidebar menu -->

            <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
            <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
                 <?php $my_tools->sidebar_footer();?>
            </div>
            <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- top navigation -->
        <div class="top_nav">
          <div class="nav_menu">
            <nav>
              <div class="nav toggle">
                <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
              </div>

              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="">
                  <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="<?php echo $my_tools->userImage();?>" alt=""><?php $my_tools->fullname();?>
                    <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                  </a>
                 <?php $my_tools->profileLink();?>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /top navigation -->

        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">
          <div class="">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_content">

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="x_panel">
                            <div class="x_title">
                              <span style="color:black !important;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;">Date Wise Report</span>
                              <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="x_content">
                              <center>
                               <div style="width:300px">
                                 <form action="view_date_wise_report.php" method="POST">
                                  <input type="text" required name="fromdate" style="margin-top:10px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" id="datepicker"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                  <input type="text" required name="todate" style="margin-top:10px;" id="datepicker1" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" >
                                  <br >
                                  <input name="show_report" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Show report">
                                  <input type="text" id="datepicker"> 
                                 </form> 
                               </div>
                              </center>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->

        <!-- footer content -->
          <?php $my_tools->myFooter();?>
        <!-- /footer content -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php include("js.php");?>

    <script src="../vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>



        <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

  <script src="js/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You appear to be loading the jQuery and the jQuery UI *after* your script call. I suspect you have a `.datepicker() is not a know function` type of error in console. Content like CSS and JS are available in the order they were loaded in the page.

Comment: What's the error in console?